# How to order SQL by duplicates with an inner join?

Tags: sql, count

The query:

```
SELECT results.Title, results.Tags
FROM results
INNER JOIN tags
ON results.ID = tags.ID
WHERE tags.Tag 
IN (?,?,?)
```

The above returns a lot of duplicates. I want to order the results, most duplicated at top. Ordered by the count of the Tags column. (results.Tags)

I then will group the results

```
GROUP BY results.ID
```

Example results:

```
Title       Tags
Book 9      Blue, Green, Rivers
Book 1      Trees, Mountains, Rivers
Book 4      Dogs, Cats, Rivers
Book 1      Trees, Mountains, Rivers
```

Desired results:

```
Title       Tags
Book 1      Trees, Mountains, Rivers
Book 4      Dogs, Cats, Rivers
Book 9      Blue, Green, Rivers
```

Duplicates at top.

What I have tried. It failed though:

```
SELECT results.Title, results.Tags
FROM results
INNER JOIN tags
ON results.ID = tags.ID
WHERE tags.Tag 
IN (?,?,?)
ORDER BY COUNT (Tags) //This makes the query error
GROUP BY results.ID
```

Comment: Is the purpose of the inner join purely to remove results that have nothing in that table? I ask because you aren't selecting anything from it.

Comment: WHERE tags.Tag. I am eliminating rows with the JOIN.

Comment: The `order by` goes after the `group by`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT X.Title,
       X.Tags,
       X.CNT
FROM
  (SELECT results.ID
          count(tags.ID) AS CNT
   FROM results
   INNER JOIN tags ON results.ID = tags.ID
   WHERE tags.Tag IN (?, ?, ?)
   GROUP BY results.ID) X
INNER JOIN tags ON X.ID = tags.ID
ORDER BY X.CNT
```

Answer (score 1):

From your tries,this is what i figured out.May be you have to use a subquery. If you could provide some sample data it would be much clearer

```
SELECT TITLE,TAGS,COUNT(*)
FROM
     (
      SELECT results.Title as Title , results.Tags as Tags
      FROM results 
      INNER JOIN tags
      ON results.ID = tags.ID
      WHERE tags.Tag 
      IN (?,?,?)
)
GROUP BY TITLE,TAGS
ORDER BY TAGS DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Title, Tag, count(a.ID) AS CNT
FROM ( 

  SELECT results.Title, tags.Tag, results.ID
  FROM results
  INNER JOIN tags
  ON results.ID = tags.results_ID
  WHERE tags.Tag 
  IN (?,?,?)

) AS a
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY CNT DESC";
```

I added an ID column.
Create the main query. Enclose it in parentheses and label it.

```
(main query) AS a
```

Then above select the the information you want from that query. In my case the count of duplicates.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM (main query)AS a
```

At the end after parenthesis group the duplicates and order them by count

```
    GROUP BY a.ID
    ORDER BY CNT DESC
```